# Sending output to a dictionary

Tags: python

I'm just a beginner at this but was looking for some help. I'm trying to make a spot it game and I have a card generator (taken from: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1303497/what-is-the-algorithm-to-generate-the-cards-in-the-game-dobble-known-as-spo)
Im trying to send the print output to a dictionary where the card number is the key and the generated card ids are listed in a set as a value.

This is what I have so far:

```
nIm = 4
n = nIm - 1
r = range(n)
rp1 = range(n+1)
c = 0
a=dict={}


# First card
c+=1
for i in rp1:
    a['Card %2d:' %c]=(i+1)
    print(a) 
print()

# n following cards
for j in r:
    if j not in r:    
        c = c+1 
    a['Card %2d:' %c]=(1) 
    print(a)
    for k in r:
        a['Card %2d:' %c]=(n+2 + n*j +k) 
        print(a)
    print()
```

Does anyone have any ideas how I can do this?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I looks like you are setting the key/value pairs to your dict ok with statements like:

```
a['Card %2d:' %c]=(i+1)
```

and

```
    a['Card %2d:' %c]=(n+2 + n*j +k)
```

I do not see the ids you mention.  Assuming your ids are in a list called `ids` you could add them to your dict like so:

```
a['ids'] = ids
```

Here's what `a` would look like afterwards.

```
print(a) # {'Card  2:': 4, 'ids': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}
```

This assumes `ids = [1,2,3,4,5]`.

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close to it. For each card, you first need to create an empty set as a value within the dict, and then call the set's "add" method to add each id to the set.

```
# First card
c+=1
a['Card %2d:' %c] = set()
for i in rp1:
    a['Card %2d:' %c].add(i+1)
    print(a) 
print()

# n following cards
for j in r:
    if j not in r:    
        c = c+1 
    a['Card %2d:' %c] = {1}
    print(a)
    for k in r:
        a['Card %2d:' %c].add(n+2 + n*j +k) 
        print(a)
    print()
```

Also, at the beginning where you have "a=dict={}", you can just say either

```
a = {}
```

or

```
a = dict()
```

Looks good! Later on you might take a look at "defaultdict" in the collections module which you could use to automatically create an empty set (or other kind of value) as a default value when the key doesn't exist yet in the dictionary. But what you have works fine.